# Split a tree into equal parts by deleting an edge

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory, split, longest-path

I am looking for an algorithm to split a tree with N nodes (where the maximum degree of each node is 3) by removing one edge from it, so that the two trees that come as the result have as close as possible to N/2. How do I find the edge that is "the most centered"?

The tree comes as an input from a previous stage of the algorithm and is input as a graph - so it's not balanced nor is it clear which node is the root.

My idea is to find the longest path in the tree and then select the edge in the middle of the longest path. Does it work?

Optimally, I am looking for a solution that can ensure that neither of the trees has more than 2N / 3 nodes.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If you have no data about the tree's layout balance, you could start out with a degenerate tree (say, 100 in the left arm and 50 in the right arm), ending up with a 50/100 split afterwards and back in the same boat.

Comment: Yes, but taking the longest path whose length will be 150 and taking the middle edge (75th or 76th on the path) will split it into equal parts. The question is whether such an optimal edge will always exist (I don't think so).

Comment: A degenerate tree is basically a linked list. e.g. the only node with two children is the root node. So you'd have two paths through the tree from the root. down the left with 100 linear nodes, and down the right with 50. Splitting the longest path (the 100 node branch) would split 100 into 50/50, plus the remainer in the right branch, so you've transformed your tree from 100/50 to 50/100.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood me. The input is actually a graph with non-oriented edges, meaning that the longest path I intend to find is the "maximum possible distance between two nodes". Finding the longest path in a general graph is NP-complete. But the algorithm that outputs the graph is designed so, that the output graph is always a tree (not a tree data-structure but a tree graph).

Comment: I don't believe that your algorithm works.  Consider a fully balanced ternary tree with a long chain of nodes that enters the root.  In this case, taking the longest path and cutting at the halfway point will give you the complete ternary tree and a simple linked list.  The tree will have exponentially many more nodes in it than the linked list.

Comment: Obvious homework. I'm disappointed, SO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe that your initial algorithm works for the reason I mentioned in the comments.  However, I think that you can solve this in O(n) time and space using a modified DFS.

Begin by walking the graph to count how many total nodes there are; call this n.  Now, choose an arbitrary node and root the tree at it.  We will now recursively explore the tree starting from the root and will compute for each subtree how many nodes are in each subtree.  This can be done using a simple recursion:

- If the current node is null, return 0.
- Otherwise:

  - For each child, compute the number of nodes in the subtree rooted at that child.
  - Return 1 + the total number of nodes in all child subtrees

At this point, we know for each edge what split we will get by removing that edge, since if the subtree below that edge has k nodes in it, the spilt will be (k, n - k).  You can thus find the best cut to make by iterating across all nodes and looking for the one that balances (k, n - k) most evenly.

Counting the nodes takes O(n) time, and running the recursion visits each node and edge at most O(1) times, so that takes O(n) time as well.  Finding the best cut takes an additional O(n) time, for a net runtime of O(n).  Since we need to store the subtree node counts, we need O(n) memory as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can't find any algorithm to do this in all.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri- Sorry, can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Yes, this will work. Thanks. I was thinking about counting the nodes on one side of the edge and on the other, but a simple approach would be O(n^2). Your algorithm is linear, which is great. Thanks again.

Comment: Very nice algorithm. One remark: the first part of counting the vertices is unnecessary, because after the second part finished we also have the number of vertices in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

If you see my answer to [Divide-And-Conquer Algorithm for Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193574/divide-and-conquer-algorithm-for-trees/8194117#8194117), you can see I'll find a node that partitions tree into 2 nearly equal size trees (bottom up algorithm), now you just need to choose one of the edges of this node to do what you want.

Your current approach is not working assume you have a complete binary tree, now add a path of length `3*log n` to one of leafs (name it `bad` leaf), your longest path will be within one of a other leafs to the end of path connected to this `bad` leaf, and your middle edge will be within this path (in fact after you passed bad leaf) and if you partition base on this edge you have a part of `O(log n)` and another part of size `O(n)` .